# A query about lexical scoping

Tags: scope, lexical-scope

I try to understand lexical-scoping. In lexical-scoping, I have this code, C like syntax:

```
main{
    f1(){
       int y = 8;
    } 

int y = 1; //*

f1();     
}
```

After the execution of `f1()` line, will the value of `y` variable in main (I put * next of it) remain 1 or change to 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will remain 1. You have two completely distinct variables. Changes to one do not affect the other.